# How can I improve accuracy of my ensemble (or anywhere in the code where I can increase accuracy)?

Tags: classification, machine-learning-model, data-cleaning, accuracy, ensemble-modeling

I am pretty new to machine learning, so if my code is not good, please bear with me.

```py
import pandas as pd
import os
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn import tree
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
import numpy as np
from imblearn.combine import SMOTETomek
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import RepeatedStratifiedKFold
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV

!wget -q --show-progress "https://storage.googleapis.com/inspirit-ai-data-bucket-1/Data/AI%20Pioneers/Heart%20Disease/heart.csv"
patient_data = pd.read_csv("heart.csv")
patient_data = patient_data[['age', 'sex', 'cp', 'trestbps', 'chol', 'fbs', 'thalach', 'exang', 'target']]
column_names = {'age':'age','sex':'sex','cp':'chest_pain', 'trestbps':'blood_pressure','chol':'cholesterol','fbs':'high_blood_sugar','thalach':'heart_rate','exang':'exercise_pain','target':'disease'}
patient_data = patient_data.rename(column_names,axis=1)
patient_data['chest_pain'] = (patient_data['chest_pain'] > 0).astype(int) #1 for yes, 0 for no
patient_data['disease'] = 1 - patient_data['disease'] #1 for yes, 0 for no
patient_data = patient_data[['age', 'blood_pressure',  'heart_rate', 'sex', 'chest_pain', 'exercise_pain', 'disease']]

X = patient_data[['chest_pain', 'exercise_pain', 'heart_rate', 'blood_pressure', 'sex', 'age']] #FILL ME IN
y = patient_data[['disease']]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

smote_tomek = SMOTETomek(random_state=42)
X_res, y_res = smote_tomek.fit_resample(X_train, y_train)

reg = LogisticRegression(C=1.623776739188721, penalty='l1', solver='liblinear')
tree = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy', max_depth=30, max_features='sqrt', min_samples_split=4)
rf = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=4, max_features='auto', min_samples_split=5,n_estimators=41)
svc = SVC(kernel = 'poly', C=1000.0, gamma = 0.001)
gnb = GaussianNB(var_smoothing = 2.848035868435799e-05)
ensemble = VotingClassifier([('cf1', reg), ('cf2', tree), ('cf3', rf), ('cf4', svc), ('cf5', gnb)], voting = 'hard')
cross_val_score(ensemble, X_res, y_res).mean()
```

The dataset link is given in the code.

The dataset is the Cleveland Clinic Heart Disease Dataset (303 samples), and I'm trying to classify whether or not the person has heart disease or not. I made a ensemble with regression, svm, random forest classifier, decision tree classifier, and gaussian naive bayes models. I also used hyperparameter tuning, but maybe there was something that I missed that could be improved on.

I'm getting accuracy from ~$75\%$ - ~$84\%$ (maybe it could be higher, but I haven't seen anything higher yet). I was wondering if I could increase this accuracy, whether it is in the ensemble itself, or the data, number of features, etc.

I also resampled the data set SMOTETomek from `imblearn`, and am not sure whether that was a good idea or not. If not, should I use a random over (or under) sampler, or something else? I would also like to know if I am missing any steps in cleaning the data.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.